# MIPS: how to manipulate strings stored in program arguments?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, mips

So basically the input of the program is 2 separate strings in the program arguments section. They can either be 0x... (hex), or 0b... (binary). The code I have so far is :

```
li $v0, 36
lw $t1, ($a1)
lb $t2, 2($t1)
syscall

li $v0, 36
lw $t3, 4($a1)
lb $t4, 2($t3)
syscall
```

The `li $v0, 36`'s are just prints to check if I got the value.
The main problem is that `$t1` and `$t3` have the correct memory address. I can see that in `$a1`'s memory address there are stored two separate memory addresses for the string location. `$t1` and `$t3` contain those, while `$t2` and `$t4` are supposed to shift over and read the second character.

For some reason, no matter what the input of the program arguments, this always prints 2. If I change the syscall to 34 it will print `0x00000002` and if I change it to 11 to print a char, as usual, it will print a box. I just need to identify if it is an x for hex or b for binary, so I can edit the inputs accordingly. Any help would be awesome.

EDIT : Even if I do syscall 11 on either a 2 shift OR a 1 shift, it prints a box. Like a [] instead of an actual character.

Comment: syscall 36 prints the integer in $a0, right? But you don’t show what is in $a0. (Maybe it’s argc?)

Comment: lb $t2, 2($t1) loads the *third* character of the string. 1($t1) is the second character and 0($t1) is the first.